# php importing ASCII from txt file

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, fgets

Im iporting a txt file using the following function

```
$fp = fopen($storagename, 'r');
while ( !feof($fp) ){
    fgets($fp, 2048);
    $delimiter = "\t";
    $data = str_getcsv($line, $delimiter);
    echo $data[0];
}
fclose($fp);
```

$data[0] = 8400
when im inserting the value of data[0] to a mysql db it gets a weird form og
"8 4 0 0"

As i figured the number is somehow encoded so the following function:

```
bin2hex($data[0])
```

returns a string of "0038003400300030000d00"
How can i convert this to a simple int ?

Comment: Looks like it's double-byte encoded; simple solution (if you know that all the values should be ASCII.... `$data[0] = str_replace("\x00", '', $data[0]);`

Comment: yes that did the trick! thanks..

Comment: That won't work if you have any non-ascii text.  What program produced the text?

Comment: well im not sure, it is some CRM software custom built that i dont have access to. do you have a good explanation on how to deal with it in another way ?